# Can you prevent the Windows TileWindows function from restoring ALL windows to their previous size?

Tags: c#, windows, smalltalk

I've been making a sort of a Window menu/manager in smalltalk. I've added a button to automatically tile all of my smalltalk windows using the Windows [TileWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633554(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

The problem is when i do this, as it says in the Windows [TileWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633554(v=vs.85).aspx) remarks, **ALL** maximized windows are restored to their previous size.

Is there a way prevent TileWindows from doing this? Or do i have to "manually" re-maximize all the windows I'm not tiling?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the behaviour of the TileWindow windows function. You need to enumerate (EnumWindows) all maximized toplevel windows and re-maximize them after the call to TileWindow. To improve reduce flickering, you should hide them.

Both hiding and maximizing is done with the ShowWindow function

Comment: Yea, thought so:(. Thanks for the tip about hiding the windows!